# Rails 3.2 - How to establish a has_many relationship with an existing data table and foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have 50Mbytes of "CTE" data in an existing postgresql database.  The CTE `name` field is constrained to be unique and not null. Here is the structure of the data:

```
dbnva=# \d+ ctedata
                                  Table "public.ctedata"
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 name        | character varying(100) | not null  | extended |              | 
 status      | text                   |           | extended |              | 
 phase       | text                   |           | extended |              | 
 description | text                   |           | extended |              | 
 refs        | text                   |           | extended |              | 
 comments    | text                   |           | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "cvedata_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Has OIDs: no
```

I need to create a Rails model `CTE_Collection` that `has_many` CTE records using the CTE `name` field as the foreign key.  My first thought was to use something like this:

```
class Cte < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :status, :phase, :description, :refs, :comments
end

class CteCollection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cte, :class_name => "Cte", :foreign_key => "name"
end
```

My questions:  Will this approach work?  Is the CTE `name` field set up to function correctly as an ActiveRecord foreign key? Is there a better approach to establishing ActiveRecord relationships with an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your primary key and table name differ from the convention, you will have to specify them explicitly in you model

```
class Cte < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ctedata"
  self.primary_key = "name"

  belong_to :cte_collection, foreign_key: :name

  attr_accessible :name, :status, :phase, :description, :refs, :comments
end
```

This approach has worked well for me while working with existing (mysql) databases. I am not aware of any other approaches.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks straightforward enough.  I'll give it a try.  Will I need to do anything special in the migration file to indicate this foreign key relationship?

Comment: It doesn't quite work.  Using the solution above, in IRB I query a single record with this call:  mycte = Cte.where("name = ?", 'CTE-2011-0343'). The correct record is found. However the results come back surrounded in square brackets [#<Cve name: "CTE-2011-0343,...>] and mycte.name returns "Cte" instead of "CTE-2011-0343".  If I manually create a record in IRB, everything works while it's in memory. But when I write it to the DB and then query it back into IRB, the manually created record has the same problem.  Thoughts on how to get the record returned w/o the square brackets?

Comment: where() returns ActiveRecord::Relation. You probably want to use find()
`mycte = Cte.find('CTE-2011-0343')`

Comment: If you still want to use _where_ you can get a single record using first(). `Cte.where("name = ?", 'CTE-2011-0343').first`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification/hand-holding.  As you can tell, I'm pretty much a nube at all things database and ActiveRecord related.